# How to add labels inside and outside to the particular slice using core plot?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

How to add labels inside and outside to the particular slice using core plot like below image?[image]

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: yes i tried only one label either outside or inside  able to add

Comment: please update question with the relevant code you have and what output you are currently getting

Answer (score 2):

Use the plot's data labels for the values inside the plot. Add annotations with the other details outside. Core Plot doesn't have any way to draw those connecting lines to the annotations, so you'll have to render those into the annotation content yourself.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am going with your suggestion.